# Racket - Inject special variables into macro code

Tags: macros, racket

I'd like to inject special variables into a macro for compile time binding.

So, for example, the following form:

```
(define-route (my/route)
  (some-proc @@request)
  (some-other-proc @@request))
```

should expand to:

```
(some-code)
...
(lambda (request)
  ...
  (some-proc request)
  (some-other-proc request))
```

where request is bound to the request in the generated code, at all the places specified by the caller.

I'm not sure how to best go about it.  Is this a more common pattern that racket macros provide the ability to do, or do I have to do it manually?

If so, should I recursively loop through the body pattern, looking for any symbols matching '@@request and then replace them?   I notice that syntax->list isn't recursive in this way, ie

```
(syntax->list #'(printf "first: ~a\" (get-var (other-proc)))
```

is 3 syntax objects not 4, and the third syntax-obj is 2 more.  So I assume I need to manually recur here, but maybe there is a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps using [syntax-parameterize](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxparam.html) (and its variant, [splicing-syntax-parameterize](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/splicing.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/splicing..rkt%29._splicing-syntax-parameterize%29%29)) should do the trick?  It's a standard tool when you want to have keyword-like things, and where the macro needs to rewire the keyword's meaning based on the context.

Here's what it looks like:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/stxparam
         racket/splicing
         (for-syntax syntax/parse racket/base))

(define-syntax-parameter @@request
  (lambda (stx)
    (raise-syntax-error #f "Use outside of a define-route" stx)))

(define-syntax (define-route stx)
  (syntax-parse stx 
    [(_ (name:id) body:expr ...)
     (syntax/loc stx
       (begin
         (printf "blah blah blah\n")

         (define name
           (lambda (request)
             (splicing-syntax-parameterize ([@@request
                                             (make-rename-transformer #'request)])
               body ...)))))]))

;; example
(define (f r)
  (printf "f sees: ~s\n" r))

(define-route (my/route)
  (f @@request))

(my/route 42)
```

The syntax-parameterization rewires uses of `@@request` in the lexical context of a `define-route` so that it refers back to the `request` that's being bound by the `lambda`.  If used outside the context of a `define-route`, it'll try to raise a sensible error message.

(You *could* do this the way you initially planned, to recursively walk though the structure of the syntax object and pick out the `@@request` elements.  It's just more work than you need to do, unless the requirements are really unusual.)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Racket (and especially the community) continue to impress.